# Assign Array to Property in PHP constructor function

Tags: php

Is it possible to store an array as an object property in PHP?

I am building an article class that pulls various information about a research article and stores them as a properties in an object. Since the number of authors vary per research article, I would like to store them as an array in an $authors property, rather than store each author as a separate property. In this code sample, I realize this problem results from working with a poorly designed table, but nonetheless, I would like to see how this code could be used to store an array as an object property.

```
<?php
     Class Article {
       public $id;
       public $authors;
       public $article_name; 
       public $journal;
       public $volume_number;
       public $issue_number;
       public $article_location;

       public function __construct($id, array $authors, $article_name, $journal,
                                  $volume_number, $issue_number, $article_location) 
       {
          $this->$id = $id;
          $this->$authors = $authors;
          $this->$article_name = $article_name;
          $this->$journal = $journal;
          $this->$volume_number = $volume_number;
          $this->$issue_number = $issue_number;
          $this->$article_location = $article_location;
      }
     } 
     //function to pull Article information from Articles Table
     function getArticle($id){
           try {
               $query = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE ID = :ID";
               $db = Db::getInstance();
               $results = $db->prepare($query);
               $results->execute([':ID'=>$id]);
               $row = $results->fetch();
               $authors = array(); 
               if(!empty($row['author'])){
                  $authors[] = $row['author'];
               }
               if(!empty($row['author2'])){
                  $authors[] = $row['author2'];
               }
               if(!empty($row['author3'])){
                  $authors[] = $row['author3'];
               }
             //This repeats for a while. 

             return new article($row['ID'],  
                               $authorList,  
                               $row['article_name'],
                               $row['journals'], 
                               $row['volume_number'], 
                               $row['issue_number'],
                               $row['article_location']);
           } catch (PDOException $e) {
              return "Unable to pull articles from the Articles table.";
              echo  $e->getMessage();
           }
      }
```

Comment: what's the problem here?

Comment: I am getting an "Array to String Conversion Notice" and then when I attempt to call the $authors property I am getting "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access empty property "
$exampleArticle = getArticle(1);
$exampleArticle->$authors;

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to store an array as a property.

The problem is that you use properties wrong.

```
$this->$authorList
```

Is wrong, you should use:

```
$this->authorList
```

Your code currently creates properties for your class based on the original property's value - if `$article_name` has the value of 'ABCD', `$this->$article_name` creates and fills the property 'ABCD' - being the equivalent of `$this->ABCD = $article_name;`, meaning you won't be able to access the value in the original property. It's the same with `$this->$authors = $authors;` - if you are passing an array as `$authors`, your code will try to store it as a string, making the situation even worse. Removing the `$` before `$authors` solves this issue too.

Also, when you use `$authorList[]`, you are pushing values into a local variable, not into the class property. It's not necessarily the wrong way to do it, as long as you copy the local variable's content into the property, but I would strongly suggest not to use variables named after properties. It makes your code harder to maintain, as it can confuse developers.

Comment: Thanks, that was my problem. That's what I get for coding at 4 am.

Comment: @Jacob Yeah, I made some mistakes before too because I was tired to death. Believe me, sleeping is more important. At least you don't have to debug the nightmare you wrote next day.